# Branching logic in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Can I use branching logic while creating a form in MS Access 2013? I want a question (which is a combobox) in one of the forms to appear only if a particular option is selected in the previous question (again a combobox). If it is possible to apply branching logic, how do I go about it? Help in detail including steps and relevant syntax wherever necessary will be appreciated.

Comment: Have in mind please, that SO is a code helping, not a code writing, and indeed not an application writing forum.

Comment: You can use the `.Visible` property of controls to hide or show them.